# Reading and writing in Excel file with multiple programs accessing

Tags: c#, .net, excel

My task:

- Get data from a website and write it to an Excel file with real time (0.5 - 1s use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)
- While the program write data to the Excel file, I want to open this file with (Excel or something like it) to see the data, chart...

So how can I read and write the Excel file in the same time? Or can I use the other way?

Comment: InterOp services may not give you tight control over read and write locks on the file... It might be tricky.  Or impossible.  (Depending how fast you read and write etc)

Comment: But in theory it is possible...Albeit very difficult.  You might be better with Google Apps like Excel or whatever its called

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.. also there are other options to use besides `InterOp`

Comment: @Grantly it about 0.5 - 1 second

Comment: As @MethodMan said, show us what you have tried so far...  Then more people might join in and assist

Comment: Are you getting data to a DataTable or DataGridView? I have solution where  it export dataGrid to a Excel using Interop and Opens it using Office Excel.. If You want i can share it with you...